# "ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy" during pip install opencv-python on python 3.10

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Recently I install Python version 3.10, but in the OpenCV installation process I faced the following error:

```
 error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\umath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalartypes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\core\src\multiarray\scalartypes.obj" failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  ----------------------------------------
```

does anybody has a solution to help me??

Comment: try this `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: A couple of recent SO tell us that packages like `numpy` cannot yet work with 3.10.  Wait till the upgrade process is complete.